# HTML CSS & Javascript Responsive Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive

I'm relatively new to coding and I've been trying to make a responsive multi-list dropdown navbar. I have made the navbar using HTML and CSS however it isn't very responsive when I change the screen size.

I don't want to use bootstrap. and I am aiming hamburger which compresses the buttons into a single column and then expands when I click on a button to show the sub-links. I believe media queries would be possible but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML / CSS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px
}

a {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  color: #FF8240;
}

#nav {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #FF8240
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: White;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.dropdown-toggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-toggle button,
.home {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: rgb(196, 19, 19);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-toggle button:hover,
.home:hover {
  color: #FFF940
}

.DropdownList :hover {
  color: rgb(196, 19, 19);
}

.DropdownList button:focus+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Hungry Burger Company</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/HBCStyleSheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One|Permanent+Marker|Roboto+Slab:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Main Container-->
  <header id="nav">

    <nav>
      <div class="dropdown-toggle">
        <h1 class="Logo">HBC</h1>
        <button><a href="#" class="home"></a>Home</a></button>
        <div class="DropdownList" id="About Us">
          <button>About Us</button>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="DropdownList" id="menu">
          <button>Menu</button>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Off The Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Build a Burger</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="DropdownList" id="Coms">
          <button>Contact Us</button>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Join Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Find Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="Javascript/HBC.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, If I understood what you mean exactly. Here is the code that does what you want you can test it with this link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G24ZV5OQJ8EB
Or You can [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G24ZV5OQJ8EB) directly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Hungry Burger Company</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/HBCStyleSheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One|Permanent+Marker|Roboto+Slab:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!--  Main Container-->
  <header id="nav">

    <nav style="width:100%;">
      <div class="dropdown-toggle">
        <h1 class="Logo">HBC</h1>

        <button id="cc"><a href="#" id="cc" class="home"></a>Home</a></button>
        <div class="DropdownList" id="cc">
          <button>About Us</button>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="DropdownList" id="cc">
          <button>Menu</button>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Off The Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Build a Burger</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="DropdownList" id="cc">
          <button>Contact Us</button>
          <ul id="cc">
            <li><a href="#">Join Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Find Us</a></li>
          </ul>


        </div>
      </div>
       <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>  

    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="Javascript/HBC.js"></script>
</body>
<style>
#cc{
display:block;
}
.sidebar{
display:none;
}
#mySidebar{
display:none;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;

}

h1{
    font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;

    letter-spacing: 5px
}


a{
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    color:#FF8240;
}

#nav {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #FF8240;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;

}

.dropdown-toggle {
    height: 10vh;
    display: flex;  
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;

}

.dropdown-toggle {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle ul{
    position: absolute;
    background: White;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 90px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; 
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(10px);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.dropdown-toggle a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-toggle button,
.home {
    background: none;
    border:  none;
    color: rgb(196, 19, 19);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-toggle button:hover,
.home:hover {
    color: #FFF940
}

.DropdownList :hover {
    color: rgb(196, 19, 19);
}


.DropdownList button:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0px)
}
#nav{

width:100%;
}
.openbtn {
display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  display:block;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  display:block;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
#mySidebar{
display:block;
}
#nav{
display:block;
}
#cc{
display:none;
}
/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a> <br>
      <a href="#">About Us</a><br>

           <a href="#">Who We Are</a><br>
       <a href="#">What we do</a><br>


<div id="main">
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Can I get it to dropdown from below the orange header and fill full width of mobile device